# Vim replacement with wildcard and special characters

Tags: xml, search, vim, replace, wildcard

Is it possible to perform wildcard replacement on string that contains lots of special characters?

String to search for:

```
<value="&lt;level/&gt;abc123"/>
```

Replace with:

```
<value="&lt;level/&gt;"/>
```

I basically want to get rid of all the abc123 in whole document.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace a specific part in a string with Vim, you can use the \zs and \ze tags, which will indicate the pattern to be replaced. To your example, it should be as follows:

```
:s#<value="&lt;level/&gt;\zsabc123\ze"/>##g
```

The separation with the **#** character is done so that Vim does not get confused with the slashes (/) in your string, and the final g indicated that you want that substitution applied to all occurrences of the **abc123** string in the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

Use Atalajaka's solution.

If you do not want to manually type in the long complicated string which you search for, a **better** way than wild card is to select the long string using the `v` command, press `"ay` to yank the long string into register `a`.

```
:%s#Ctrl+Ra##g
```

`Ctrl+R` means that you press and hold the `Ctrl` key, and press `R`.

Add `\zs` and `\ze` before and after `abc123` respectively.

The command line will become

```
:%s#<value="&lt;level/&gt;\zsabc123\ze"/>##g
```

Press Enter, all the instances of `abc123` will be gone.